# Remove duplicates by line in Spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science

I am doing some work with the [Pyspark MLlib FPGrowth algorithm](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html) and have a rdd with repeated examples of duplicate transactions contained within each line.  This is causing the model training function to throw an error due to these duplicates.  I'm fairly new to Spark and am wondering how to remove duplicates *within* the line of an rdd.  As an example:

```
 #simple example
    from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth

    data = [["a", "a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d", "e"], ["a", "a", "c", "e"], ["a", "c", "f"]]
    rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
    model = FPGrowth.train(rdd, 0.6, 2)
    freqit = model.freqItemsets()
    freqit.collect()
```

So that it looks like:

```
#simple example
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth

data_dedup = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d", "e"], ["a", "c", "e"], ["a", "c", "f"]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data_dedup)
model = FPGrowth.train(rdd, 0.6, 2)
freqit = model.freqItemsets()
freqit.collect()
```

And will run without error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could write a map function that will clear the duplicates. This function takes one entry as input and outputs the entry without duplicates. Let's call this `f`. The you run `rdd.map(f())`. Result of this should be a "cleaned" RDD.

Comment: Thanks @LiMuBei, any advice on what that function would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

This will remove the duplicated.

Comment: That's it, I appreciate the help